# Serialization C# object to json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

What is the best way to create a C# class that can be serialized to as:

```
marks:          [
             { c: [57.162499, 65.54718], // latitude, longitude - this type of coordinates works only for World Map
               tooltip: 'Tyumen - Click to go to http://yahoo.com', // text for tooltip
               attrs: {
                        href: 'http://yahoo.com',            // link
                        src:  '/markers/pin1_red.png'        // image for marker
                       }
             },
             { xy: [50, 120], // x-y coodinates - works for all maps, including World Map
               tooltip: 'This is London! Click to go to http://london.com',
               attrs: {
                        href: 'http://yahoo.com',            // link
                        src:  '/markers/pin1_yellow.png'     // image for marker
                       }
             }
            ]
```

In above code we assign either assign 'c' or 'xy' but not both at the same time.
I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.
The only thing I want is a C# class that can be serialized to above code.

Comment: Do you want a class with two properties or two classes?

Comment: @WouterdeKort: actually a class 4 properties {c,xy, tooltip,attrs}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Marks
{
    public List<latlon> marks = new List<latlon>();
}

public class latlon
{
    public double[] c;
    public int[] xy;
    public string tooltip;
    public attributes attrs;

    public latlon (double lat, double lon)
    {
        c = new double[] { lat, lon };
    }
    public latlon (int x, int y)
    {
        xy = new int[] { x, y };
    }
}

public class attributes
{
    public string href;
    public string src;
}
```

The code to test it looks like this:

```
string json;

Marks obj = new Marks();
latlon mark = new latlon(57.162, 65.547)
    {
        tooltip = "Tyumen - Click to go to http://yahoo.com",
        attrs = new attributes()
        {
            href = "http://yahoo.com",
            src = "/markers/pin1_red.png"
        }
    };

obj.marks.Add(mark);

mark = new latlon(50, 120)
    {
        tooltip = "This is London! Click to go to http://london.com",
        attrs = new attributes()
        {
            href = "http://yahoo.com",
            src = "/markers/pin1_yellow.png"
        }
    };

obj.marks.Add(mark);

//serialize to JSON, ignoring null elements
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```